# Show custom values on x axis for Bar Graph kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, elk

I am having some records in elastic-search. I have created Vertical Bar for showing these records. Records can be differentiated on the basis of key and there can be multiple records with same key. There are 10 keys in total.

On x-axis I have selected aggregation as terms and the field is key.

[image]

On y-axis I have selected aggregation as count.

[image]

My graph plotted is

[image]

In the graph on x-axis I have keys. Now for these keys, I have to map to some data.

Eg: 08e470d3-14bd-4a5f-9756-df67aff1a793 = kita1

So basically instead of showing the key I have to show the name.
Is there some way I can map these keys to these names?

Answer (score 0):

it would be good to know what version of Elasticsearch you are using. Since different versions of the elasticsearch stack offer different options. Reggarding your question I would solve that by modifying the data (i.e. I would make the mapping creating a new field with the desired values) This can be solved by many ways: by using elastic commands or for instance using python, pandas and eland. The eland library can help you to convert your elasticsearch index into a pandas dataframe and also from the dataframe save it to elastic document back. Check the examples in: [eland](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/eland/current/dataframes.html)